# A Stable Unique Id for Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, serial-number, imei, unique-id

I am developing an android app by using xamarin forms (in the future, maybe a uwp app will be developed, not an ios App).

I've tried some libraries such as

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin

In the library, the property named Id is actually Build.Serial and there is a note for that

> Id This should not be used as a stable ID as each vendor on Android
>   may or may not set it to a different value and on iOS it is changed
>   when applications are uninstalled.

and I tried the method GenerateAppId from the same library but it generates different id numbers for each call.

After that, I tried https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.DeviceInfo/ 
and the DeviceId is also Build.Serial

As I understand, this id may change. So I need a really stable unique Id from the device and I will be able to generate the same unique Id from the same device (I do not want to save it, thus I will get the number by a certain calculation)

I've used

```
Android.Provider.Settings.Secure
.GetString(context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
```

and `Android.OS.Build.Serial`

I get two different numbers but not sure if one of them is stable.

Is there a way to access really IMEI or serial number or both or something unique (I prefer that it does not require any permission but if I have to, then it is OK)

Answer (score 0):

The Android ID that @Ialit Maheshwari suggests is actually not the IMEI. You can use the Android Telephony Manager to request the IMEI, but then you'll also need the permission "READ_PHONE_STATE", which can be regarded as very intrusive by users (they will have to agree to something like "Allow application to make and manage phone calls").

Ultimately, I would also suggest using the Android ID. For my own purposes of identifying users it works fine.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54272/how-to-get-the-imei-number) is information on how to get the IMEI on both Android and iOS. However, in case of iOS it is not even possible to submit Apps to the App Store if you access the IMEI.

Comment: IMEI is no longer available to developers.

Answer (score -1):

You can get Device IMEI number form below code `Settings.Secure.GetString(Forms.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId)`